# Optimize collision detection in 2d

Tags: algorithm, optimization, collision-detection

I need a way to efficiently find if a point lies within one of a set of triangles. Is there any algorithm faster than O(n), n = #triangles?

Comment: Are coordinates integer? If yes - what is workspace size in pixels?

Comment: No, coordinates of both axes are bound to all real numbers.

Comment: OK. Do triangles fill the most of space? I mean - with small fill factor you can use binary search by vertical and horizontal intervals occupied by triangles

Comment: The triangles differ in size too much to generalize them to a specific point

Comment: Are you going to do repeated querying? The first thing that came to my mind was to build something like interval tree. However the creation of the tree is nlog(n) (and the structure for the triangles can't be built faster than O(n) in any case) so it would be worth it only if your use case was to query repeatedly with an option for pre-computing that could be costly.

Comment: In this specific situation, there exists a collection of tris. I loop through each tri and do a specific task if any of the tri's vertices are within any other scanned tri. So I think its more optimal to consider construction time over query time in this case. I do appreciate the idea, however.